# Formula into Excel Table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to insert the following formula into the third column of my Excel Table "Transactions". If I enter it manually, it works, but if I try to enter it using a subroutine I get the Error 1004. Not sure how to solve this.  Here is a code snippet:

```
    Sub test3()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim lCol As ListColumn

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Transactions")
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
    Set lColName = lo.ListColumns(3)

    lColName.DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Staff[CREDENTIALS],MATCH([@[Staff, Last Name]],LastName,0)),"")"
    End Sub
```

All I really need to do is to put the formula into the first row of the table (row 2) in the third column "Staff, Credentials".  It is pulling from another Excel Table "Staff".

Comment: As you rightly say, all you need to do is to put your formula in the first cell. Then, why do you attempt to put it into the columns entire range? Try `lColName.DataBodyRange.Cells(1).Formula = [whatever]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is coming from your formula (I know you mentioned it works when you manually enter it however when I try I'm getting an error), try changing `[@[Staff, Last Name]]` to `Staff[Last Name]`

Also, you'll need to escape the `""` in the `IFERROR` formula, the below code should work:

```
Sub test3()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim lCol As ListColumn

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Transactions")
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
    Set lColName = lo.ListColumns(3)

    lColName.DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Staff[CREDENTIALS],MATCH(Staff[Last Name],LastName,0)),"""")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.